# What happens behind the curtains when I get a page in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Suppose that I have a piece of code that states:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

What happens with the webdriver and the webpage when that last command is run? Here comes my theory:

- Something (is it the webdriver or my computer or perhaps something
  else) sends a GET request to a the server.
- HTML is taken from the response and is loaded is injected into
  webdriver (or perhaps not if the requests was sent from the
  webdriver)

**Please excuse me if my assumptions may seem dumb.**

Comment: driver doesn't send directly to server. It sends url to Firefox and Firefox sends request to server and receives response from server, then Firefox renders page, runs JavaScript scripts, and then driver can get HTML from Firefox. Webdriver controls Firefox (or other Browser, or Web Widget ie. from Qt library, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver is a specification published by W3C. You can check it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/).

It's responsibility to every browser "manufacturer" implement the specification, so the browser can support it. Selenium provides an API to use it more easily ([link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)).

The following is the Selenium Source Code for Java with some useful javadoc - `WebDriver.get(url)` method.

```
/**
* Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an HTTP GET operation,
* and the method will block until the load is complete. This will follow redirects issued either
* by the server or as a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. Should a meta-redirect
* "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout is over, since should
* the underlying page change whilst your test is executing the results of future calls against
* this interface will be against the freshly loaded page. Synonym for
* {@link org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation#to(String)}.
*
* @param url The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL
*/
void get(String url);
```

The implementation for `get(String url)` code in `RemoteWebDriver.java` is:

```
public void get(String url) {
    execute(DriverCommand.GET, ImmutableMap.of("url", url));
}
```

If want to dive deeper, you can clone the repo from Github from [this address](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) and check the whole implementation of `protected Response execute(String driverCommand, Map<String, ?> parameters)` in the class `RemoteWebDriver.java`.
It will show you in more details what happens when a page is requested.